# Use of F-table to find a confidence interval for a ratio of variances

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, confidence-interval

What are other ways to write the CI for the ratio of the variances $\sigma_1^2/\sigma_2^2$?

One way is $((s_1^2/s_2^2)(1/f_{1-\alpha/2,n_1-1,n_2-1}),(s_1^2/s_2^2)(f_{\alpha/2,n_2-1,n_1-1}))$

Could you provide alternative ways of the confidence interval?

Thank you

Comment: Not absolutely sure of your notation. Let $W = S_1^2/S_2^2,$ where $S_i^2$ are sample variances of independent samples, also let  $\varphi = \sigma_1^2/\sigma_2^2.$ Then $W/\varphi  \sim \mathsf{F}(n_1 -1, n_2 - 1);$ let $L$ and $U$ cut 2.5% from lower and upper tails of that dist'n, respectively. Then $.95 = P(L < W/\varphi < U) = P(W/U < \varphi < W/L)$ so that $(W/U, W/L)$ is 95% CI for $\varphi.$ I guess that's about what you have. // It is not at all clear why you want an alternative way to write the CI. Is it simply because you can't find $L$ in your printed F-table? Or something deeper?

Comment: @BruceET It' because I have some solved exercise were is used $((s_2^2/s_1^2)(1/f_{1-\alpha/2,n_2-1,n_1-1}),(s_2^2/s_1^2)(f_{1-\alpha/2,n_1-1,n_2-1}))$ as you can see that's different than  $((s_1^2/s_2^2)(1/f_{1-\alpha/2,n_1-1,n_2-1}),(s_1^2/s_2^2)(f_{\alpha/2,n_2-1,n_1-1}))$ so I don't know if both are equivalent or if there is a typo in the first or second formula

Comment: If I am interpreting the notation correctly ($\alpha = .05,$ etc.),  I think there is no misprint and the two formulas are equivalent. Please see my Answer with a numerical example and specific references to printed tables and software.

Comment: oh ok, thank you @BruceET :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have $n_1 = 10$ observations $X_{1i}$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_1=20, \sigma_1=2)$ and $n_2 = 15$ observations $X_{1i}$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_1=30, \sigma_1=5)$. Then $\varphi = 4/25 = 0.16.$ Perhaps (rounded):

```
x1 = round(rnorm(10, 20, 2),2);  x2 = round(rnorm(15, 30, 5),2)
x1
[1] 22.70 21.39 19.49 23.15 22.31 18.80 19.65 21.09 19.18 20.55
x2
 [1] 29.74 31.69 31.84 24.65 32.46 30.24 28.52 32.03 38.30 29.98 24.76 28.11
[13] 45.31 24.00 21.16
```

Sample variances are $S_1^2 = 2.3956,\, S_2^2 = 35.3782,$ so the observed variance
ratio is $W = S_1^2/S_2^2 = 0.6771.$

```
var(x1); var(x2)
[1] 2.395632
[1] 35.37823
w = var(x1)/var(x2);  w
[1] 0.06771488
```

The relevant F-distribution is $\mathsf{F}(9, 14).$ In R statistical software
the values $L =0.2633$ and $U = 3.209$ of my Comment can be found as shown below. Please
notice that the 'percentage points' (often denoted by subscripts) refer to
*upper* tails, whereas the R quantile function (inverse CDF) looks at
probabilities in *lower* tails.

```
qf(c(.025, .975), 9, 14)
[1] 0.2632998 3.2093003
```

From most printed tables of F-distributions, you can get $U = 3.209$ directly, but $L$ only indirectly.
Please look now at a such a table so you know exactly what I mean.

From a printed table that gives only upper-tail cut-off values, you can
obtain $L = 0.2633$ by taking the reciprocal of an upper-tail cut-off value, as shown below. Notice that the degrees of freedom are interchanged. Please look
now at a printed table to find the value `3.798` that cuts probability 2.5% from
the *upper* tail of $\mathsf{F}(14, 9).$

```
1/qf(.975, 14, 9)
[1] 0.2632998
qf(.975, 14, 9)
[1] 3.797952     # rounded value available in printed table
```

Finally, a 95% confidence interval for $\varphi,$ in my example with fake data,
is given as $(W/3.209, W/0.2633) = (0.0211, 0.2572),$ which does include
the value $\varphi = 0.16,$ used to generate my fake data.

```
w/qf(c(.975, .025), 9, 14)
[1] 0.02109958 0.25717789
w/qf(.975, 9, 14);  w*qf(.975, 14, 9)  
[1] 0.02109958
[1] 0.2571779
```

*Note:* I have used the notation of my Comment throughout, partly because it
avoids confusion between upper and lower tails and partly because it is
compatible with the conventions used in most statistical software. Someday
soon I suppose textbooks will stop filling a dozen pages at the end with printed
tables of various distributions used in inference. Software is increasingly available; it is more flexible to use and provides more accurate values.